# Spring,form won't submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

I am working with form in jsp in Spring,but i have difficulties to submit it with "post" method..
My form looks like this:

```
<c:url var="action2" value="/saveConfig/try" />
<form:form name="formakonfig" id="formakonfig" action="${action2}" method="post" modelAttribute="seatingConfiguration">
        <form:hidden path="mesto" id="mestoo" value=""></form:hidden>
        <form:hidden path="restoran" id="restoranre" value=""></form:hidden>
        <form:hidden path="reon" id="reonn" value=""></form:hidden>
        <form:hidden path="raspolozivost" id="raspolozivostt" value=""></form:hidden>
     </form:form>
     <button type="submit" style="width: 152px; height: 25px; margin-top:-60px; margin-left:150px; position:fixed;">Sacuvaj konfiguraciju</button>
```

I have javascript file where i'm setting values for hidden fields `"mesto"`,`"restoran"`,`"reon"`and `"raspolozivost"`,inside `$(document).ready`.

```
$("#mestoo").val(stringSadrzajaTabele);
$("#restoranre").val(vrednostSelekta());
$("#reonn").val(stringSadrzajaTabele);
$("#raspolozivostt").val("slobodno");
```

Also I have controller where i'm trying to access(but i can't access it..)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveConfig/try",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView snimanjeKonfiguracije(@Valid SeatingConfiguration seatingConfiguration,BindingResult bindingResult,ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request){

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {    
            return new ModelAndView("zaposleni","formErrors",bindingResult.getAllErrors());
        }
        model.addAttribute("workerRegistration", new WorkerRegistration());
        model.addAttribute("restaurantRegistration", new RestaurantRegistration());

        String temp1=seatingConfiguration.getMesto();
        String temp2=seatingConfiguration.getRestoran();
        String temp3=seatingConfiguration.getReon();
        String temp4=seatingConfiguration.getRaspolozivost();
        System.out.println(temp1);
        System.out.println(temp2);
        System.out.println(temp3);
        System.out.println(temp4);

        model.put("poruka", "Dodato!");
        return new ModelAndView("zaposleni","model",model);
    }
```

Does someone have patience who worked in Spring to see what is possible problem?It would mean very much to me!:)Thanks anyway!

Comment: what is the exact problem you have? 404 error or not happens when you click submit?

Comment: Nothing happens when i submit..I have similar form but there i have event select.onchange and there i put $().val()..here i put it inside click(function(){});,i wanted to enable when something on page is clicked,then i can submit information from that what is clicked and put it hidden id value,and then pass to controller..if it is possible somehow..in that form it works,but here it won't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first code, your submit button is out of the form, if you are not sending form via js, this should be the case.  PLace submit button inside the form element as below:

```
<form:form name="formakonfig" id="formakonfig" action="${action2}" method="post" modelAttribute="seatingConfiguration">
        <form:hidden path="mesto" id="mestoo" value=""></form:hidden>
        <form:hidden path="restoran" id="restoranre" value=""></form:hidden>
        <form:hidden path="reon" id="reonn" value=""></form:hidden>
        <form:hidden path="raspolozivost" id="raspolozivostt" value=""></form:hidden>
         <button type="submit" style="width: 152px; height: 25px; margin-top:-60px; margin-left:150px; position:fixed;">Sacuvaj konfiguraciju</button>
  </form:form>
```